# wp media regenerate unknown --image_size parameter

Tags: media, wp-cli

It is said in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) that we can set the --image_size parameter to regenerate all images for only this size. However, I am getting this for this command:

```
Error: Parameter errors:
 unknown --image_size parameter
```

I am trying the following example from the documentation:

```
wp media regenerate --image_size=large
```

How do I regenerate images only for a specific size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to duplicate the issue when running WP-CLI [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/tree/v1.1.0), but the command worked successfully when I [updated](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/) to the nightly build using:

```
wp cli update --nightly
```

The `--image-size` parameter was added to [wp-cli/media-command](https://github.com/wp-cli/media-command) on [April 13, 2017](https://github.com/wp-cli/media-command/pull/9) after the [current stable release of WP-CLI v1.1.0](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/2017/02/01/version-1-1-0/) on February 1, 2017. This feature is available in the nightly builds and will likely appear in a future stable release.

**Update:** As of [WP-CLI version 1.2.0](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/2017/05/31/version-1-2-0-released/), `wp media regenerate --image_size=large` will work right out of the box.